# NSObjCMessageLoggingEnabled

Tags: ios, ios-simulator

This does not seem to work for me.

Setting the environment variable OBJC_HELP to 1 outputs content to the console so it seems I'm setting the environment variable correctly.

However, if I set NSObjCMessageLoggingEnabled to 1 in the same way it's supposed to create a log in /tmp. However, I see no recent logs there.

Note: I'm running on the iPhone simulator with Xcode4 using iOS4.3.

Any suggestions?

Comment: NSObjCMessageLoggingEnabled should be set to YES

Comment: Thanks - leave this as an answer and I'll tick it...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

NSObjCMessageLoggingEnabled should be set to YES

Comment: not working for me :( using iOS 6.1. Can you please tell me the location of the temp folder is it the same one which is inside the app.

Comment: The file shows up with a path like `/tmp/msgSends-59707`